# Material-UI autocomplete - Only show options when click icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

Is it possible to make the options list only shown when click the arrow icon instead of the textfield?

I checked the documentations but couldn't find the solution.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl2gj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete has the open prop that you can use to control it :

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  <Autocomplete
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => {
                setOpen(true);
            }}
            onClose={() => {
                setOpen(false);
            }}
```

Comment: Hi Samira, thanks for answering, but If I click the textfield, it will trigger onOpen event, isn't it? Is there a props only listen for the event when click the icon?